# Migrating Android apps from Eclipse to Android Studio with multiple user-created libraries and dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, migration, gradle, android-studio

How can you migrate to Android Studio using an Eclipse project depending one many user libraries?

I've tried using the Eclipse export to gradle but I can't seem to get it to work.

Also, my project sources are not in the workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android Studio [0.4.2](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio042released), you can now import the Eclipse project from Android Studio.

Note: This is *different* from Eclipse's export Gradle project function.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Verify the version is **>0.4.2**, if not update to it. (I had to download it from the [tools website](http://tools.android.com/download/studio))
3. Import Project...
4. Navigate to the actual Android app project, the highest level project (*not the workspace or the directory containing all the eclipse projects*)
5. Follow the wizard to import it all

The advantages of doing it this was is that :

- makes the migration less painful
- generates gradle files
- restructures your project as a gradle/Android Studio project

Comment: You don't need to install Gradle 1.9 separately.

Comment: @ScottBarta Thanks, I've removed that step now :)